# How to fix cut romex line that was cut before receptacle

Tags: wiring

Can the romex be spliced in line and then shrink wrapped ? Or  bring receptacle outletbox closer to cut line.

Comment: One of the real experts will give a full answer. But my general understanding is that splices need to (a) be accessible (i.e., definitely can't be buried behind drywall) and (b) preferably (not sure if "must") inside a junction box (e.g., the receptacle outlet box).

Comment: What size is the cable? (14/2? 12/4? 10/3?)

Comment: There is actually now a UL listed splice kit for NM cable (romex) intended to be used without a box or enclosure. https://www.grainger.com/product/TE-CONNECTIVITY-300V-Nonmetallic-Splice-6HKE8